# integral with a product of sines

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I am wondering if the following integral has a solution in closed form:

$
\int_0^1 \prod_{j=1}^d \sin \left( \left( \frac{\pi}{2}+(m_j-1)\pi  \right) x^{t_j}\right)dx
$

where $d > 2$, $m_1,...,m_d$ are positive integers and $t_1,...,t_d$ satisfy $t_1+...+t_d=1$, $t_i \geq 0$, $i=1,...,d$. The points $\left( \frac{\pi}{2}+(m_j-1)\pi  \right)$ are zeros of the cosine, so I guess that this should help. Yet, having a product with more than two sines sharing tha same $x$ makes things more involved. Am I missing anything stupid?

Comment: what is the purpose of the $\pi/2$?

Comment: Letting $0<z_1<z_2<...$ denote the positive zeros of the cosine function, the sine functions in the product have to be: $\sin(z_{k_j} x^{t_j})$, with $k_j \geq 1$

Comment: Because of the fractional powers of $x$ under the sines, a tractable solution is unlikely. Even simplified cases are awful https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sin(pi+t%5E(3%2F4)%2F2)+for+t+from+0+to+1